# Summing two columns at row level

Tags: sql, db2

Quick question. I have a query which outputs results that look a bit like this:

```
Customer_ID | Measure_1 | Measure_2
------------|-----------|----------
111         | 1         | 2
222         | 3         | 4
333         | 5         | 0
444         | 0         | 6
```

I want to add together the values of measure_1 and measure_2 for each customer, so that the results look like this:

```
Customer_ID | Total
------------|------
111         | 3
222         | 7
333         | 5
444         | 6
```

Does anyone know how to do this please?

Comment: `select Customer_ID, Measure_1 + Measure_2 as Total ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some of the ways to solve this problem -

```
Select Customer_ID, Measure_1+Measure_2 "TOTAL";

Select Customer_ID, Measure_1+Measure_2 TOTAL;
```

As you can see I only changed the ways by which we can write allies for the column but the main query always remained the same.

Comment: You can also use `` Select Customer_ID, NVL(Measure_1,0)+NVL(Measure_2,0) AS "TOTAL"; `` If you have data consisting of null values or if you insert null data also in columns, it will work for that also.